# Blockchain.info Receive Payment callback problem

Tags: api, blockchain.info, payment

I am setting up a website to accept bitcoins using blockchain.info API, it's all set, code is ok, tested and working, I receive payments and everything but blockchain.info just won't call the callback url. 
Since my websites traffic is going through cloudflare, I thought at first disabling firewall and few other security measurements would fix this but still not calling the callback..

Thanks

*SOLVED*

I just noticed that I had not adjusted firewall for callback file properly which blocked blockchain.info access, tested this on some other site and it's working, thanks everyone for trying to help.

Comment: anybody has any idea ??

Comment: Although there are people on here that sometimes answer blockchain.info questions, this site is not related to them. You're probably better off contacting their helpdesk/forum/whatever they have.

Comment: @bitcxz I'll take a look

Comment: @bitcxz What does the [callback form](https://blockchain.info/api/blockchain_wallet_api) say?